# Appium - How to manage scroll speed on Mobile Gesture for ios

Tags: ios, appium, e2e-testing

For my e2e tests on `iOS`, I'm running some `appium` commands like the following examples:

```
browser.execute("mobile: scroll", {
   element: elementId,
   toVisible: true
});
```

or simply

```
browser.execute("mobile: scroll", {
  direction: "up"
});
```

but I noticed that the scroll incredibly slow. Is there a way to increase the speed and gain time running my tests? I have already check out the documentation [here](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/ios/ios-xctest-mobile-gestures/index.html#mobile-scroll) but haven't found anything interesting.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [`mobile:swipe` command](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/ios/ios-xctest-mobile-gestures/#mobile-swipe), it should be working much faster:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("direction", "up");
//if you are scrolling to some MobileElement
if (myElement != null) {
    params.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) myElement ).getId());
}
browser.executeScript("mobile: swipe", params);
```

There is also [Swipe](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Swipe) command available via [SeeTest Appium Extension](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/SeeTest+-+Appium+Extension) which is easier to use in terms of syntax

Comment: It does solve the problem for a basic `scroll` up but not really when I need to reach a specific position.